# Jenkins slave fails to execute after VM reboot

Tags: jenkins, virtual-machine, slave

I had a perfectly working AWS VM, which I duplicated in order to have similar environements for stage and production.

I stopped the VM to create a snapshot, but now, when I launch a build with the jenkins slave on it, I get this error :

```
Building remotely on <nodename> in workspace /home/ubuntu/workspace/<workspaceName>
Installing JDK 
java.io.IOException: Unable to find JDK with ID=
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.locate(JDKInstaller.java:422)
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.performInstallation(JDKInstaller.java:134)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:107)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:205)
    at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:130)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:355)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2228)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:932)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:828)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:484)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1274)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Alternatively, I sometimes got this precision

(between *"Installing JDK"* and *"java.io.IOException: Unable to find JDK with ID="*)

```
FATAL: Failed to get Environment Vars from build
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get Environment Vars from build
    at jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BPPlugin.getEnvironmentVariables(BPPlugin.java:84)
    at jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BPPlugin.perform(BPPlugin.java:93)
    at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshPreBuildWrapper.setUp(BapSshPreBuildWrapper.java:64)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:154)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:536)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
```

I didn't notice what causes those extra lines to appear, since I tried everything I thought about, including

- Flushing every files in my user directory (.jenkins, workspace, and every jdk related file from slave.jar and the jdk dir to the install scripts...)
- Recreating my jenkins slave and / or build, either from scratch, or as a copy of my initial build.
- Recreating again the VM from the snapshot (just to be sure I didn't screw anything up in-between)

JDK is already here, of course.  Everything worked just fine before this reboot.
So my first question is "Why does it try to install a JDK ?"

I have no idea about the "Environment Vars" it's trying to get, and am not aware of any change in the VM config, so I'm quite out of ideas.

Comment: Update : looks like the problem is on the master server (or with Jenkins slave plug-in ?), since other jobs fail too now.  I don't think any config was altered, so I'll investigate the cause and update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was "just" that the configured JDK setting value disappeared from Jenkins.

I have absolutely no idea WHY it did, since no one would have modified this setting, and it's in a submenu which needs to be opened first, making it protected from manipulation mistakes.

Anyway, here's how I fixed it.  It's as simple as setting the JAVA_HOME value in Jenkins:

• Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure system 

  • Click on "Installations JDK"

  • Untick "install automatically" (My environnement was already set up, I just needed to set the variable again)

  • Set JAVA_HOME (in my case, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` ), and optionally, name your install

EDIT : since some other builds continued to fail, I had to create a symlink on one of my older servers, which had java installed in /usr/bin/java

`mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/`

`ln -s /usr/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

I also added a JAVA_HOME environment variable with the same `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` value in Jenkin's conf.  Probably redundant

---

Our Jenkins version is 1.609.3 (checked in `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` ), 

Please, comment if you experience the same problem, since I **really** doubt this mistake originated from a user.

Comment: Somehow on restarting jenkins this exact thing happened to me. Builds started failing, my blood ran cold, I found your answer, verified that indeed my JDK configuration had gotten munched somehow after installing a few plugins and restarting.. Updated my JDK config, restarted again - nobody even knew what happened. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue but noticed that the system didn't have the appropriate version of jdk installed.  On Jenkins it looks like it installs the jdks in $JENKINS_HOME/tools/hudson.model.JDK (in our case /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8).

We updated followed the steps above and it worked perfectly.

- Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure system
- Click on "Installations JDK"
- Untick "install automatically" (My environment was already set up, I just needed to set the variable again)
- Set JAVA_HOME (in my case, /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk8 ), and optionally, name your install